# More elegant way to convert 4 bytes to 32bit integer

Tags: ruby

I'm converting arrays consisting of four byte values to 32bit numbers by executing the following code:

```
a = [0, 16, 82, 0]
i = a.map { |e| "%02x" % e }.join.to_i(16)
# => 1069568
```

It works as intended, but I wonder if there's a more elegant way to perform this task. Maybe not utilizing strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have one byte, that would be the result as is. If you add one byte to the right side, that would make the original result move two positions to the left (which means multiplying by 0x100, or 16 ** 2 = 256), and add the new byte. You can repeat this as many times as there are bytes.

```
a.inject{|acc, byte| acc * 0x100 + byte}
# => 1069568
```

Comment: Alternatively `(acc << 8) + byte`

Comment: Alternatively, `acc  <<  8  | byte`

Comment: @CarySwoveland of course! You don't even need the parentheses when using `|`.

Comment: Forget about my previous comment here.

Comment: @sawa no worries, my attention span is like 5 seconds ^_^

Answer (score 6):

Using [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [`unpack1`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-unpack1):

```
a = [0, 16, 82, 0]

a.pack('C4').unpack1('L>')
#=> 1069568
```

`C4` means 8-bit unsigned (4 times) and `L>` means 32-bit unsigned (big endian).

However, `pack` returns a binary string, so this is not string-free.

Comment: Less than 20 seconds ago I was reading this question and thinking this sounds like a `pack/unpack` question, musing that it was too bad that Stefan was not on this. Then, bam, your answer appeared!